# Axiom of separation

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The Axiom of separation states that, if A is a set then $\{a \in A ;\Phi(a)\}$ is a set.
Given a set $B \subseteq A$, Suppose I define $B=\{ a \in A ; a\notin B \}$.
This, of course leads to a contradiction. Because we define $B$ by elements not from $B$. My queation is: what part of the axioms sais that this kind of definition is not possible?

Thank you!

Comment: The part where you reuse $B$.

Comment: Your example is often called a "circular definition".  To the untrained eye recursive definitions might appear to be circular ones, but a proper recursion will rest on a base case, much like a proof by induction.  Your "definition" of $B$ has no base case, no starting point.  It is not a valid definition of a set.

Comment: $a\notin B$ is not a formula because $B$ is not a set so u cant use it to define set.

Comment: @user52045 actually, he started by assuming that $B\subseteq A$, so $B$ is certainly a set. And the right hand side of the definition is also a set. The problem is that the axiom does not allow you to set any two sets equal to each other (ie, you cannot just reuse letters however you like).

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft: Yes and no. "Given a set $B \subseteq A$, Suppose I define $B=\{ a \in A ; a\notin B \}$". So OP defines $B$ incorrectly and in the same time assumes that its a set. By definition it dont have to be set but he assumes it is. So by assuming incorrectly that $B$ is a set he gets contradiction. At least thats how i see it. If I m wrong pleas let me know.

Comment: @user52045  In the context of axiomatic set theory, the assumption "is a set" is meaningless.  All variable symbols denote sets.  Tobias is correct in that the problem is that the formula purported to define $B$ is not a valid definition, and in fact contradicts $A$ being nonempty.  Not every formula in which the variable symbol $B$ occurs can serve as a definition of $B$.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing at all to stop you defining a set $\Sigma$ such that $x \in \Sigma$ iff $x \in A \land x \notin B$, so $\Sigma = \{x \in A \mid x \notin B\}$.

But what you've shown is that $\Sigma \neq B$!

No problem so far.

What you can't do is then go on (having a knock-down argument to show that $\Sigma \neq B$) to assert, as you do, $\Sigma = B$. What could possibly legitimate that???

Answer (score 2):

You were given a set and named it $B$.

You defined another set, and named it $B$.

Just because you've given them the same names doesn't mean they are actually the same set. Your contradiction only appears because you've confused yourself and thought the two sets were the same since you gave them the same name.